# Selenium can't get this class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm trying to get the button clicked but Selenium cant reach that class :

```
access-grants__flows-area__create-button container

key_cli_btn = self._get_xpath("//div[@class='/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/div'")
    print(key_cli_btn)
```

This xpath is invalid :

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector:    `Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@class='/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/div' because of the following error:
```

`SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@class='/html/body/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYyx9.png)/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/div'' is not a valid XPath expression.

or I've tried to start from this div class:

```
dashboard__wrap__main-area__content-wrap
```

but I don't know how to get "child"

Edit1:

```
    def _get_xpath(self, xpath: str) -> webdriver:
    return self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
```

[image]

Comment: This locator is absolutely invalid. can you provide a link to the page you working on and clarify what element you trying to access?

Comment: Try this Xpath instead what you are tryinh: `//div[@class='access-grants__flows-area__create-button container']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what `self._get_xpath` is, but generally something like this probably should work:

```py
key_cli_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='access-grants__flows-area__create-button container']")
```

Comment: Yes , I confused class name with path..... Thank you